# How to make a nicely styled popup in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make something like this site has: http://www.eventipity.com/

When you press "city" it gives you a sort of a pleasant-looking styled popup.

I am working on this page: http://www.problemio.com/index_new.php and when you mouse over a category, I would like to pop up a list of sub-categories for that category.

Is there a way to do this so that the popup would look very nice? Something that is better than just opening up a generic dialog in jQuery?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Here's a plugin that might serve your purpose: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: A much better answer than the modal popup. If I was GeekedOut, I'd go this route. Thanks for the good link, Aaron.

Comment: Thanks guys, just so I understand how to use it...I am trying to do some test like  $("[Test]").tooltip(); but nothing happens :)

Comment: Basically, for each of your `<a>` elements you want associated with a tooltip, you'll want to add an adjacently-following `<div>` element with `class="tooltip"`. You should probably also give these "trigger" anchors an identifying class for easy selection. Then, on `$(document).ready()`, call `$('a.myClass').tooltip();` to enable the tooltip functionality. You can see a simple implementation here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.htm

Answer (score 3):

Check out the jQuery modal dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal